# The averages of a subharmonic function over concentric balls increase with radius

Tags: sobolev-spaces, harmonic-functions, elliptic-equations

Let $B_r$ a ball of radius $r$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $u \in H^{1}(B_r)$ with $\Delta u =0$ in the weak sense. I am reading a paper and the author says that : "since $|\nabla u |^2$ is subharmonic, then

$$ \frac{1}{\alpha_n s^n} \int_{B_s} |\nabla u|^2  dx \leq \frac{1}{\alpha_n r^n} \int_{B_r} |\nabla u|^2 dx \ " \tag{*}$$

I am not seeing how to prove this. Using the proof of Evans's PDE book  of the classical mean value formula for harmonic funtions I can get that

$$ \frac{1}{\alpha_n s^{n-1}} \int_{ \partial B_s} |\nabla u|^2   \leq \frac{1}{  \alpha_n r^{n-1}} \int_{ \partial B_r} |\nabla u|^2   $$

Here $\alpha_n$ denotes the measure of the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$. the part of subhamonicity I understood.

Please someone could help me to obtain formula (*)?

Comment: thanks for your commentary =)

Comment: Suggestions: use `\tag{}` for tagging formulas, and `^2` for squaring things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If spherical averages go up, so do the "solid" averages.

Let's start with an intuitive fact: if $f:[0,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is a nondecreasing function, then the running averages $F(x)=\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x f(t)\,dt$ are also nondecreasing. Indeed, a change of variable yields
$$F(x)=\int_0^1 f(xt)\,dt$$
where the integrand increases with respect to $x$. (Proof suggested by David C. Ullrich).

More generally, the weighted averages 
$F_p(x)=\frac{p}{x^p}\int_0^x f(t)t^{p-1}\,dt$ are nondecreasing; this is reduced to the above by  substitution $u=t^p$.

As a special case, let $p=n$ and let $f(t)$ be the average of subharmonic function on the sphere of radius $t$. Then $F_n(r)$ is its average on the ball of radius $r$.

Comment: You can show $F$ is nondecreasing without having to worry about differentiability by writing $F(x)=\int_0^1 f(xt)\,dt$.